# Jquery Ui Sortable blocks X-editable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using for my table the [sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#entry-examples) plugin and [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/docs.html).
I can drag and drop the rows around and with x-editable i'm able to edit the cell content.

my sortable call:

```
$('.table-schichtplan tbody').sortable({
   cancel : ".table-schichtplan-section,.table-schichtplan-break,.table-schichtplan-shift",
   refreshPositions: true,
   scroll: true,
   containment: 'parent',
   placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
}).disableSelection();​
```

x-editable (according to the fiddle):

```
$('#username').editable({
   type: 'text',
   url: '/post',    
   pk: 1,    
   title: 'Enter username',
   ajaxOptions: {
       type: 'put'
   }        
});
```

So i click on `#username` and the popup for editing appears. BUT i cant select the text with my mouse or even set the cursor position in the inputfield with my mouse.
only if i delete the sortable part it works.
it seems that the sortable plugin blocks some part of x-editable.

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/49/

I have tried something like that:

```
$('.editable-cell').on('shown', function() {
    $('.table-schichtplan tbody').sortable('disable');
});

$('.editable-cell').on('hidden', function() {  
   $('.table-schichtplan tbody').sortable('enable');
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you're applying `disableSelection()` method.